# how to get public events of facebook by LAT long/location using GraphApi

Tags: android, iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

Need retrive the public events of facebook for particular location using graph api in facebook. At present I am using the below URL to find public Events but this url returns wrong events. i have also try many others url some are giving wrong and some are just showing specific user's events.

[Link](https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=city,state,country,description,id,start_time,end_time,name,place,street,zip&q=*&center=33.716,73.066&distance=1000&type=event&limit=25000since=2016-07-01until=2016-07-11&access_token=(Token%20here))

Please suggest me if any options available in graph api to fetch the Public events for particular location.

Comment: You can not use center/distance for event searches, those apply to search for pages only. It is not possible to search for events by coordinates. (If by “specific location”, you mean events published by a particular page – then request them from the page directly, not via search.)

Comment: hoping to get any solution. i need all public event of specific City or from lat long.

Answer (score 0):

To search for events by location is not possible anymore since Graph API v2.1.

There is a workaround by searching for places by location, and then checking for events of these places.

See

- https://github.com/tobilg/facebook-events-by-location